# TSQL OVER clause: COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY a)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, window-functions

This is my code:

```
USE [tempdb];
GO

IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.t') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE dbo.t
END
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.t
(
    a NVARCHAR(8),
    b NVARCHAR(8)
);
GO

INSERT t VALUES ('a', 'b');
INSERT t VALUES ('a', 'b');
INSERT t VALUES ('a', 'b');
INSERT t VALUES ('c', 'd');
INSERT t VALUES ('c', 'd');
INSERT t VALUES ('c', 'd');
INSERT t VALUES ('c', 'd');
INSERT t VALUES ('e', NULL);
INSERT t VALUES (NULL, NULL);
INSERT t VALUES (NULL, NULL);
INSERT t VALUES (NULL, NULL);
INSERT t VALUES (NULL, NULL);
GO

SELECT  a, b,
    COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY a)
FROM    t;
```

On [this page of BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx), Microsoft says that:

> If PARTITION BY is not specified, the function treats all rows of the
>   query result set as a single group.

So based on my understanding, the last `SELECT` statement will give me the following result. Since all records are considered as in one single group, right?

```
a        b        
-------- -------- -----------
NULL     NULL     12
NULL     NULL     12
NULL     NULL     12
NULL     NULL     12
a        b        12
a        b        12
a        b        12
c        d        12
c        d        12
c        d        12
c        d        12
e        NULL     12
```

But the actual result is:

```
a        b        
-------- -------- -----------
NULL     NULL     4
NULL     NULL     4
NULL     NULL     4
NULL     NULL     4
a        b        7
a        b        7
a        b        7
c        d        11
c        d        11
c        d        11
c        d        11
e        NULL     12
```

Anyone can help to explain why? Thanks.

Comment: I could be mistaken, but I don't think COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY field) works at all...

Comment: @bluefeet -- that's what I thought -- thanks...

Comment: It does work in SQLServer 2012 - see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fe2f9/7

Comment: Hi guys, as it was said in the BOL page, the `partition by` clause is optional. "If PARTITION BY is not specified, the function treats all rows of the query result set as a single group".

Comment: @MarkBannister well look at that, I stand corrected.

Comment: Thanks @MarkBannister -- I stand mistaken...

Comment: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/filling-in-missing-values-using-the-t-sql-window-frame/

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It gives a running total (this functionality was not implemented in SQL Server until [version 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx).)

The `ORDER BY` defines the window to be aggregated with `UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` and `CURRENT ROW` as the default when not specified. SQL Server defaults to the [less well performing](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/running-totals) `RANGE` option rather than `ROWS`.

They have different semantics in the case of ties in that the window for the `RANGE` version includes not just the current row (and preceding rows) but also any additional tied rows with the same value of `a` as the current row. This can be seen in the number of rows counted by each in the results below.

```
SELECT  a, 
        b,
        COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY a 
                         ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS  [Rows],
        COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY a 
                         RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS [Range],
        COUNT(*) OVER() AS [Over()]
    FROM    t;
```

Returns

```
a        b        Rows        Range       Over()
-------- -------- ----------- ----------- -----------
NULL     NULL     1           4           12
NULL     NULL     2           4           12
NULL     NULL     3           4           12
NULL     NULL     4           4           12
a        b        5           7           12
a        b        6           7           12
a        b        7           7           12
c        d        8           11          12
c        d        9           11          12
c        d        10          11          12
c        d        11          11          12
e        NULL     12          12          12
```

To achieve the result that you were expecting to get omit **both** the `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` and use an empty `OVER()` clause (also shown above).

Answer (score 2):

If ROWS/RANGE is not specified but ORDER BY is specified, RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW is used as the default for window frame
So what does that mean, let's focus on "UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW". This gives a running total from the starting row to the current row.
But in case if you want to have an overall count then you can also specify

"UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED Following"
This considers entire data set and Over() is just a shortcut of this

```
    select a,b,
count(*) over(order by a) as [count],
COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY a 
                         RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS [Range],
COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY a 
                         ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS  [Rows],
COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY a 
                         RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED Following) AS [Range_Unbounded_following],
COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY a 
                         ROWs BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED Following) AS [Row_Unbounded_following]
,COUNT(*) OVER () AS [Plain_over]
from t 
order by [count]
```

Result is

```
a        b        count       Range       Rows        Range_Unbounded_following Row_Unbounded_following Plain_over
-------- -------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ------------------------- ----------------------- -----------
NULL     NULL     4           4           1           12                        12                      12
NULL     NULL     4           4           2           12                        12                      12
NULL     NULL     4           4           3           12                        12                      12
NULL     NULL     4           4           4           12                        12                      12
a        b        7           7           5           12                        12                      12
a        b        7           7           6           12                        12                      12
a        b        7           7           7           12                        12                      12
c        d        11          11          8           12                        12                      12
c        d        11          11          9           12                        12                      12
c        d        11          11          10          12                        12                      12
c        d        11          11          11          12                        12                      12
e        NULL     12          12          12          12                        12                      12
```