# SQL Gaps and Islands fails with 3 rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

Considering the following data

```sql
# SELECT * FROM foobar;
 id | quantity |    time
----+----------+------------
  1 |       50 | 2022-01-01
  2 |      100 | 2022-01-02
  3 |       50 | 2022-01-03
  4 |       50 | 2022-01-04
```

(note: the 4th row is simply here to illustrate the expected result, it's not necessary to reproduce the issue)

I want to extract three distinct groups based on two assumptions: 1) a new group should be created everytime `quantity` changes and 2) consecutive identical quantities should be merged in the same group. The end result should look something like this

```sql
 id | quantity |    time    |  group_id
----+----------+------------+-------------
  1 |       50 | 2022-01-01 |           1
  2 |      100 | 2022-01-02 |           2
  3 |       50 | 2022-01-03 |           3
  4 |       50 | 2022-01-04 |           3
```

I've tried implementing a gaps and island solution to this problem but it fails with this specific data, as the group end up merging rows with different quantity. Note that swapping row 2 and 3 fixes the issue. Using `DENSE_RANK` results in the same problem.

```sql
# SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY time) as global_rank,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY quantity ORDER BY time) as qty_counter
FROM foobar;
 id | quantity |    time    | global_rank | qty_counter
----+----------+------------+-------------+-------------
  1 |       50 | 2022-01-01 |           1 |           1    # global_rank - qty_counter = 0 
  2 |      100 | 2022-01-02 |           2 |           1    # global_rank - qty_counter = 1 
  3 |       50 | 2022-01-03 |           3 |           2    # global_rank - qty_counter = 1 
  4 |       50 | 2022-01-04 |           4 |           3    # global_rank - qty_counter = 1 
(4 rows)
```

How can I change this query to get the expected result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that this is simpler solved with `lag()`; the idea is to compare each `quantity` to the *previous* value, and increment a counter when they do not match.

```
select id, quantity, time, 
    count(*) filter(where quantity is distinct from lag_quantity) over(order by time) as grp
from (
    select f.*, lag(quantity) over(order by time) lag_quantity
    from foobar f
) f
order by time
```

| id | quantity | time | grp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 | 2022-01-01 | 1 |
| 2 | 100 | 2022-01-02 | 2 |
| 3 | 50 | 2022-01-03 | 3 |
| 4 | 50 | 2022-01-04 | 3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/63ISlAZw)

Comment: Additional note for SQL beginners like me reading this post and not understanding the `count() over`, @GMB's answer works because `ORDER BY` performs a running total. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14860368/5343009 for a better explanation